# Merge branch 'master' of http://stash.BI Conflicts: ABC.sql when pull in GIT

Tags: git

when i pull the Data from GIT to my Folder. it gives me message:

Merge branch 'master' of http://stash.BI 
Conflicts:  ABC.sql

what i need to do now?

Comment: Resolve the conflict then commit the merge.

Comment: `git pull` is a convenience command that runs `git fetch` and then `git merge`. The fetch step went well, but the merge step had a problem. I recommend never using `git pull`—this will have no effect on the *problem,* but you will then *know* that you are using `git merge`, and know that your next step is to learn how merge works and how to resolve merge conflicts.